# How to change text output depending on the value of x

Tags: c++

I want to create a list from one to ten. Each time it loops it adds one to `x`, I also want it to print like this.

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
      7
       8
        9
         10
```

Right now it prints like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: this is not homework. i am not enrolled in any classes im am doing this on my own. jerks j/p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pseudocode:

```
for (i: 1..10)
   for(j:1..i) //or for(j:1..(i-1)) if you want zero spaces on line 1
      print space
   print i
   print newline
```

hth

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a number and a character, that you can use to generate "*x* space characters":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        std::cout << std::string(x, ' ') << (x+1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1) Giving a complete code to a homework question won't help the asker in the long term... 2) your code prints 0..9 not 1..10 :)

Comment: That's what I'd actually do in the real world.

Comment: @Armen: (1) It will if they learn by example, like the vast majority of programmers alive today; though I do appreciate your aversion to spoon-feeding. (2) Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you can make a "spacer"-string in the loop and add a space to it everytime it runs through. Then you output the spacer-string + the number of loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to your function that represents the indention level (as a string made of spaces for example), and every time it's called you increase it by one " ".

in a loop you can make the same thing, by just adding one space per increase in your value

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[64];
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  sprintf(buf, "%%%dd\n", i + i / 10 + 1);
  printf(buf, i);
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
    std::cout << ' ';
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```